# Installing applications after Windows Updates have been installed but not yet rebooted. What problems should I expect?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-update

Big wigs in my environment will only allow for our servers to be rebooted once a month. However, patches were installed earlier this month due to a mistake but the server have not been restarted.

The issue at hand is that we need to install an application that also requires a reboot and since our window is so short I am wondering if it will cause any problems to install it before the Microsoft patches have been allowed a reboot. Will this revert any changes made to the system from the point where they were installed to the reboot?

Answer (score 2):

> Will this revert any changes made to the system from the point where they were installed to the reboot?

No, it will not.

> The issue at hand is that we need to install an application that also requires a reboot and since our window is so short I am wondering if it will cause any problems to install it before the Microsoft patches have been allowed a reboot.

This really depends on the application. Many will install just fine if there's a pending reboot. Others won't even begin. SQL Server comes to mind as one that won't, just as an example.

Basically, fire up a test environment and see for yourself.